# Disable autoIndexing on Mongo serverless instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, mongoatlas

Is there terraform resource that can enable/disable auto indexing [mongoDocu](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/performance-advisor/auto-index-serverless/) for serverless mongo instance?

I did the change in mongo ui  [mongoDocu](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/performance-advisor/auto-index-serverless/) and found out that this toggle triggers this url (with post or get )https://cloud.mongodb.com/performanceAdvisor/groups//serverless//autoIndexing

But I cannot find any atlas cli command or terraform resource that can do this.